# How can I add a command to VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, command, vscode-extensions, ctrl

We would like to contribute to the VS Code GitHub and would like to add function to some commands. However, we could not find where the commands are defined. Could anyone tell me which dir these code are in?

We tried the keybinding and workbench. But we cannot find the definition of "ctrl + p" (command palette) which we would like to edit.

Comment: the commands are defined in the `package.json` files of the extensions, and some are hardcoded by VSC by calling the command create methods. If you want to add some commands create an extension. In the extension you can call any existing command and thus decorate/use any command.

Answer (score 0):

For builtin VS Code commands, you want to implement `Action2` and then pass your implementation to a call to `registerAction2`- both of which are defined in the file [microsoft/vscode/src/vs/platform/actions/common/actions.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/platform/actions/common/actions.ts). `registerAction2`- among other things- makes the necessary calls to `CommandsRegistry.registerCommand`, `MenuRegistry.appendMenuItem` (which makes the command available from the command palette), and `KeybindingsRegistry.registerKeybindingRule`).

Note that if you don't insist on making the command one builtin to VS Code, you can just do it through an extension by [contributing a command in the extension manifest](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.commands) (`contributes.commands`) and then [registering an implementation of the command](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command#registering-a-command) (see `vscode.commands.registerCommand`). You can find VS Code's handler for command contributions in its call to `commandsExtensionPoint.setHandler` in [src/vs/workbench/services/actions/common/menusExtensionPoint.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/services/actions/common/menusExtensionPoint.ts), which you'll notice makes a call to `MenuRegistry.addCommand` so the command is accessible from the command palette.